# Advanced Symfony Routing - exclude a particular host

Tags: php, symfony

I have two routes with the same path (/about/).  I want example3.com to go to route B and all other domains/hosts go to route A. Is this possible?

For example:

```
http://example.com/about/ -> route A
http://example2.com/about/ -> route A
http://example3.com/about/ -> route B
http://example4.com/about/ -> route A
http://example5.com/about/ -> route A
```

I have route B setup to only match on example3.com in the host field, however, when I add route A into the mix, example3.com is using that instead of route B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer - you need to use the rarely used "condition" configuration for the route.

```
/**
 * @Route("/about/", name="global_about_us", condition="not (context.getHost() matches '/example3\.com/')")
 */
public function aboutUsAction() {
    return new Response('global about us'); //todo
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I generally only like the annotations for my entities, but I gave a solution below for dynamic subdomains.  It can easily be expanded to do what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to do precisely this, here is a rundown of how I did it:

In my firewall:

```
    main:
            context: user
            host: ^(app|portal)\.xxxxx\.com
            pattern: ^/
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
                success_handler: security_handler
                login_path: /
                check_path: /connect
                default_target_path: /
                failure_path: /
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: xxxxx.oauth.user_provider
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                success_handler: xxxx.authentication_handler
                failure_handler: xxxx.authentication_handler
            logout: true
            anonymous: true
        public:
            anonymous: ~
```

Of important note, is the **host** entry in the main firewall.  You'll notice I have it set to only apply to subdomains of app or portal.  Therefor something like **testing.whatever.com** would not match this firewall, and move onto the second firewall noted as public, which allows anonymous access.

Next we have to look at our *routing.yml* file, this is where the exclusions come in:

```
dynamic_homepage:
    path:   /
    host:   "{hostname}.xxxxx.com"
    defaults:
        _controller: WebBundle:Dashboard:hostLoader
    requirements:
        hostname: "^((?!app|portal).)*$"

main_homepage:
    path:   /
    host:   portal.xxxxxx.com
    defaults: { _controller: WebBundle:Dashboard:index }
```

Two things happen here.

1. If hostname starts with either app or portal, it moves onto the next (main) homepage.
2. For **ANY** other subdomain it will match and load that first route.

In your controller action you can use the *Request* object to get the subdomain requested.

eg.

```
// User requested testing.xxxxx.com
function hostLoaderAction(Request $request) {
    $hostname = $request->get('hostname'); // hostname was a placeholder in our route

    // $hostname now equals 'testing'
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it is what you looking for:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

**Updated**

You should move your routes in routing.yml like this:

```
about_example3_com:
    path:     /about
    host:     example3.com
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:aboutEx3 }

global_example:
    path:     /about
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:about }
```

Comment: No, that doesn't allow negation of a particular host.

Comment: global_example doesn't EXCLUDE example3.com and the ordering of the routes being loaded matters a lot.  This is not a solid solution in a large project.  The "condition" configuration that I listed above is what makes the most sense for me.

Comment: Agreed with OP, this is not an exclusion.  If you serve dynamic subdomains you actually need to be able to exclude specific hosts from certain routes and this example is built on the assumption that you know ahead of time what all possible hosts will be.